# AS3: code not executing

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I started my second ever FlashDevelop project (used along with Flash Professional) and it seems like something got messed up. Whenever I run the code, Flash launches the player, but doesn't react to the code I've written. I couldn't figure out how to google this problem, because I'm not even sure what exactly can be wrong. Did I mess up my classpaths or something?

Comment: How exactly does your setup work? Which program do you use to compile your code? What does the output panel of that program say?

Comment: i don't use anything aside from FD and Flash CC. Can't get any output even with 'trace' command in the constructor function.

Comment: You probably forgot to put your main (document) class's name in Flash CC's document class input field. Or have you done that?

Comment: @YarickShokopets that doesn't answer my question. It'S clear that you somehow _use_ both prgrams, but the question is **how exactly do you use both programs**? You can compile with either one. So which one do you use to "make" the .swf and how is the other one involved.

Comment: It actually was a classpath issue, everything started working when I have pointed the paths to the software. I use FD for organizing the code and Flash to compile the SWF so it's easier to place objects on the stage.

Comment: Probably a linkage problem.  In FlashPro where you put in your class paths, when you hit the pencil (edit) icon does your correct class file come up?

Comment: This was one of the reasons, yes :)